# Do large integers carry more information than small integers?

Tags: information-theory

Naively, the answer seems to be yes. Our representation of numbers in a base-ten system requires that large integers take more digits. Large numbers also take up more space when we write them in binary, and can be used to encode more information on a computer.

But as all integers represent one instance out of the set of all possible integers, their informational entropy should be equivalent, as are sides of a die in a dice game.

So, do large integers carry more information than small integers, or does the interaction of integers with a base-ten system produce different amounts of information for different integers?

Comment: How do you define information?

Comment: The Kolmogorov-complexity is in fact a measure of how many "information" a number contains. Most large numbers cannot be compreessed (that is created by a much smaller program than the program "print<number>"), hence in this sense contain more information in general, when they are larger.

Comment: Another definition of information is as an appropriate function of the probability a random integer would be the value of interest. All sufficiently large integers must be very improbable once a distribution is specified, so the information is greater.

Comment: Depends. In a language where there are only two words, but each word is 999 letters long, each one is still only one bit's worth of information. There needs to be more context.

Comment: It seems useless to talk about a game of dice if nobody can ever know how many sides each die has. But if you tell me you rolled $1$ on a $45249081$-sided die, then you have given me a lot more information than just the number $1.$

Comment: @John Douma: *How do you define information?* --- Indeed. Consider the following statement: "There exist at most $n$ integers such that $P(n)$ is true." For most people, I suspect this statement conveys more information when $n=3$ than when $n=10^{10^{100}}.$

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers: "At most 3" says that $P(n)$ is true when $n$ is an element of $\{1, \, 2, \, 3\}$ and "at most $10^{10^{100}}$ says that $P(n)$ is true when $n$ is an element of $\{1, \, 2, \, 3, \, \ldots , \, 10^{10^{100}} \}.$ The smaller number gives more information about the values of $n$ such that $P(n)$ is true.

Comment: You should think this the other way round. If "our representation of numbers in a base-ten system requires that large integers take more digits" , it's  because people try to optimize, and in human experience small numbers are more frequent than big numbers (same as in natural languages the most usual words tend to be shorter than the infrequent ones). Then, that representation implicitly assumes that all numbers are not "equiprobable" (an absurd property, BTW), but that smaller are more probable, and hence carry less information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help to think of information as a measure of *difficulty*: roughly, "more information" means "harder to describe" (the connection being that in order to describe it you have to *say more*) or "harder to *compress*" (as a string).

In light of this it should be clear that size doesn't control information: the number $$X={10}^{{10}^{10^{10^{10^{10}}}}}$$is rather large, but quite simple to describe (I've just done it);  by contrast, consider the number $$Y=4361748963429187634192343214123412345654678492734536.$$ This is - relatively speaking - *tiny*. But it's (at a glance, at least) much harder to describe.

---

Now, per your comment "Large numbers also take up more space when we write them in binary" - a key point here is that we get to choose *how* to describe the numbers in question. If I tried to write out $X$ in decimal notation, I'd be in trouble, but the point is that there is *some* way to write $X$ compactly. The issue with $Y$ is that there isn't any obvious way to "repackage" it in a simpler form. *Maybe* we're amazingly lucky and it's (say) the smallest counterexample to Goldbach's conjecture - which would give a relatively simple way to define it ("the smallest counterexample to Goldbach's conjecture") - but barring such surprises, $Y$ is in fact harder to describe (= contains more information) than $X$.

Answer (score -1):

Think about the reverse problem:  If I want to encode the complete works of Shakespeare into an integer, I don't think I can do it with anything smaller than $100.$  I could take the very large base-16 number formed from the ASCII file of all of Shakespeare's works.

So it's the case that I am able to encode more information in a large integer than in a small one.

Answer (score -1):

The amount of information is determined by the probability of the integer in your assumption, not by the value of the integer. After the source coding, all the integers take the same digits. They take up the same size of space.